# chrome-devtools://devtools/devTools.css NOT LOADING

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I paste this: `chrome-devtools://devtools/devTools.css` in my URL address bar, nothing appears.. I can see only the tab icon cycling, like when it is loading. I tried to wait several minutes, but nothing still appears.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to do?  If you're trying to view the css for devtools, you can [inspect the inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12291163/1876861) and see which stylesheets are being used.

Also, depending on which version you're using, the stylesheet names vary.  The name for the general stylesheet in my version is `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.css`

Comment: Thank you for all!!! I also really appreciate [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12291163/1876861), you gave me all that I need!!!!